# File corrupts afters uploading using FTP protocol

Tags: c#, ftp, wav

I am trying to upload some `*.wav` files to a host using FTP protocol. The thing is that, after uploading, the file is very damaged! The size of file is the same as the file on local and I can hear something in the corrupted file but noise is added too much to the WAV file.

This is the code I use to upload my files to server:

```
    public void UploadViaFtp(Object fn)
    {
        string filename = (string)fn;
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.****.com/htdocs/uploads/" + filename + ".wav");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "****");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename + ".wav");
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => box.Text += "\nFile \"" + filename + "\" Uploaded Successfully!!!"));

        response.Close();
    }
```

This is the code that records sound files for me:

```
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    struct RecUploadStruct
    {
        public DateTime timeForNaming;
    }

    public void RecUpload(Object param)
    {
        RecUploadStruct iParam = (RecUploadStruct)param;

        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("recording, press Enter to stop and save ...");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        string name = iParam.timeForNaming.Day.ToString() + iParam.timeForNaming.Hour.ToString() + iParam.timeForNaming.Minute.ToString() + iParam.timeForNaming.Second.ToString();

        mciSendString("save recsound " + name + ".wav", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);

        Thread uploader = new Thread(UploadViaFtp);

        uploader.Start(name);
    }
```

and this is some file before uploading:

[before](http://parma.fagig.com/uploads/11184020-b.wav)

and this is the file after uploading:

[after](http://parma.fagig.com/uploads/11184020.wav)

Comment: You probably shouldn't include your real credentials in the code.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650013/c-sharp-file-is-corrupt-after-uploaded-to-server help?

Comment: @KenD , it was useful. it worked exactly as i wished. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - File is corrupt after uploaded to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650013/c-sharp-file-is-corrupt-after-uploaded-to-server)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set your Ftp request to binary `request.UseBinary` to `true`.

```
request.UseBinary = true;
```

Comment: i checked that. it was not useful!

Comment: @ConductedClever Why not?

Comment: the sound is still very noisy. if you want i give you the sound!